# Returning a value in function export using promises when second function is complete

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, es6-promise

I'm trying to return a value after a promise runs a function once all promises are completed like the code below.

```
var promises = [];
var userInfo = null;
export function userRunner(userData) {
    userData.forEach(function (obj) {
        let x = fetch(apiURL1)
            .then(function (data) {
                return data.json()
            })
        promises.push(x);

        let y = fetch(apiURL2)
            .then(function (data) {
                return data.json()
            })
        promises.push(y);
    });

    Promise
        .all(promises)
        .then(function (results) {

            return plotChart(results); //How do I return this only when it's done below?

        }).catch(function (error) {
            console.log(error);
        });

}


function plotChart(obj){
    //do some work with userInfo and return userInfo
    return userInfo;
}
```

Basically onces all fetch are complete and `Promise.all` runs it calls the `plotGraph` function that returns a value. How do I return this value only when `plotGraph` is complete?

Im calling this function from another js page using `es6` like this

```
import {
    userRunner
} from './graph'
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: What value are you trying to return to where?

Comment: Hey @Nit basically 'userInfo' to another page that's importing 'userRunner'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can return the promise chain from your component:

```
export function userRunner(userData) {
    return Promise
        .all(promises)
        .then(function (results) {
            return plotChart(results);
        })
}
```

And then continue the chain in the importing file:

```
import { userRunner } from './graph'

userRunner(userData).then(function (chartedResults) {})
```

Comment: Hi @Nit I'm getting a `Cannot read property 'then' of undefined` just wanted to let you know that I am tryin to return the `userInfo` var when plotChart() is called